# Is it possible to create "Empty Solution" with Visual Web Developer 2010 Express?

Tags: vwdexpress

s it possible to create an "Empty Solution" with Visual Web Developer 2010 Express? It looks to me like that was possible to do so with VWD 2008 SP1 Express.

Anything to configure to get an empty solution? Or something similar, so that I can get more than one solution for a new application? I've VS2008 professional and I'd like to switch to VWD 2010 Express before I'm able to get VS2010 Professional edition.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, identify a folder location in which you will build solutions.

Then in VWD 2010 Express, create a New Project from the File menu. Select the Windows templates under your preferred language (ie C#) and highlight Class Library. Name your Class (ie, "Domain") and below that you have options to set your base directory for the solution folder, 'Create new solution', and provide a 'Solution name' with the 'Create directory for solution'.

You can then use the File -> Add... menu option to add resources to the your solution.

Comment: Wow! 4months later, someone has thought about me. I can't tell how it was hard to figure out all night. I tried everything and almost threw my computer over the window. Then found out on the morning what you just wrote. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I came into this problem myself
If I understand you question right this is what you want to do.

Go to File -> New Project -> (under Installed Templates) click and expand desired language (VB or C#) -> click on Web -> and to the right go down to ASP.NET Empty Web Application. That will create the necesary Properties, References, and the Web.config files.

Then just click on File -> New File... -> Click on desired language -> Click on Web -> and select what you want you include. in your case a Web Form.

That is it.