# How do I create an empty solution in Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The only link I can find anywhere is this: [Is it possible to create "Empty Solution" with Visual Web Developer 2010 Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591530/is-it-possible-to-create-empty-solution-with-visual-web-developer-2010-express)

However this is what my New Project box looks like:

[image]

There are almost no templates and Blank Solution is not one of them. I tried searching Online Templates but also no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Empty Project". Project is synonymous with solution :)

**EDIT:**

I just tried it out now, and after clicking 'Empty Project', I've been given to option to specify a name for the new solution too.  As shown below:

[image]

Note that there's even a checkbox giving you the option to create a new folder for the solution.

Comment: Project is *not* synonymous with solution.

Comment: @Sean it does, I found I have to enable that in the options menu as by default it doesn't prompt you for that information (as in my screenshot). Thanks. I'd still like to be able to create a blank solution from scratch as I can on my work pc but I guess it's simply not included in the express version. You'll see it on yours if you look in `Other Project Types > Visual Studio Solutions`.

Answer (score 3):

***Edit: Sorry, just re-read question and saw it was specific to the Express version. 
This tip only works in full version as far as I know.***

In the New Project dialog, select the "Other Project Types" section under Installed Templates. 
Visual Studio Solutions/Blank Solution is your friend.

[image]

Comment: +1 for finding this hidden option. The difference with a top-level project is that in a solution you can Add a new web site, which is much different from a top level project with type of Web Site or Web Application which has no dir App_Code .

Comment: (Can't edit the above comment anymore) There is always a Solution, even if you just create a new Project from scratch. You might not see the solution mentioned in the Solution Explorer, but can still add/create a second project (e.g. "web site" watch out: different file path) using the Add option under the File menu. The Solution will become visible in the Solution Explorer. See: [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/girishp/archive/2010/06/03/visual-studio-vanishing-solution-node-when-adding-projects.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

What about the "Empty Project" option?

That should do what you want.